# MVC Download Excel File on server issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm working on a page that displays a link to an Excel file that we have stored within the application.

The link on the view is as such:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel sheet", "Download", new { @class = "a" })
```

which in turn calls:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
     return new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("~Content//SMT Specimen Entry Template.xlsx"), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
}
```

Simple enough however when I click the link I get the following:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at `https://oursite.com/Home/Download?class=a` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.  Feel like this should be really simple but stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I think  your Action link is being created with your attributes as parameters.  Add an empty array for the Parameters.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel sheet", "Download", new{ },new { @class = "a" })
```

or it could be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel sheet", "Download", new { @class = "a" },new{  })
```

One of those should work.